# Adding x:Name attribute to a UserControl which is used inside another UserControl causes a "Cannot load file or assembly" exception

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm working on a WPF application. My application includes a few projects. In one of the projects I have a user control which uses another user control from a **different** project.
if I don't give the user control a name, i just add it through xaml, the application works ok.
But, if i add the x:Name attribute to the user control, the application compiles ok, but at real time i get a "Could not load file or assembly" exception.
Trying to add the usercontrol in the code behind instead of xaml - gave the same results - the application crashed at realtime.

my xaml looks like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns:my="clr-namespace:UserControls.CtrlTwo;assembly=Project1".../>

<Grid>
<my:CtrlTwo x:Name = "ctrlTwo"/>
</Grid>
```

any idea why it happens and what could I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reference the user control from the start up project.
(i have no explaination why)